# Close combat after a rank is removed from an attack on any flank

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I asked a similar [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/19163/3048) recently. However, i believe this question to be different since that question was in regard to "incomplete" ranks. This question is in regards to a rank that is completely removed from a rear attack.

---

Legend:

- Funit = friendly unit.
- Eunit = enemy unit.

---

A few scenarios here.

1. `FunitA` contains a unit of infantry and my general. They are attacking `EunitA` in the front. `EunitB` is attacking `FunitA's` left flank. My general is on the far right flank of `FunitA`. The entire unit of `FunitA` is killed except my general. `EunitB` is no longer in base contact with my general. What happens in this scenario? Does `EunitB` automatically move into base contact with my general or can they still attack even though they are no longer in base contact?
2. `FunitA` contains a unit of infantry and my general. They are attacking `EunitA` in the front. `EunitB` is attacking `FunitA's` left flank. `FunitB` is attacking the rear flank of `EunitB`. `FunitB` kills the entire rear rank of `EunitB` and is no longer in base contact with any models from `EunitB`. What happens in this scenario? Does `FunitB` automatically move into base contact with `EunitB` or do they attack across the gap even though they are not in base contact with any model of `EunitB`.
3. Same scenario of number 2. Except there is a `EunitC` attacking the left flank of `FunitB` at the same time. `FunitB` kills all of `EunitB's` rear rank and loses base contact with `EunitB`. What happens now?

Thanks, and i know it is wordy. I tried my best to explain the scenarios. Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some tricky scenarios there - I'll do my best (with diagrams)

**Scenario 1**

[image]

**What happens if `EUnitA` kills `FUnitA` but not the general?**

The first thing to test for is whether the general runs away, given he's flanked, outranked and has had his entire unit die around him this is a very real possibility. I'll assume he doesn't either because he's stubborn, unbreakable or has rolled snake-eyes.

The first rule to remember is that you cannot die out of combat deliberately, however it it occurs and `EUnitA` is released then they are no longer in the combat and can move, charge and shoot as per normal. [This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-die-out-of-a-combat) considers what happens if they're not released from combat because of a challenge.

**Scenario 2**

[image]

**What happens if `FunitB` kills the entire back rank of `EunitA` and is no longer in combat?**

They take a step forward and remain in combat. Move as few units as possible.

**Scenario 3**

[image]

This one is vague, it's one of those scenarios which occurs so rarely it's not really covered in the rules and you have to use a little common sense.

The issue is that if `FUnitB` don't take a step forward you're losing a significant number of attacks per turn.

My advice would be to:

- Keep it as a single combat
- Move `FUnitB` forward
- Allow your opponent to bring `EUnitC` with you so they do not lose any attacks in the process.

I don't have a rulebook quote to back me up but I would suggest that nudging the units so it's fair for everyone.

If you really can't decide which is fairest then both state your cases, roll a die and abide by the result. People can spend longer working out these tiny edge cases than playing the rest of the game - at the end of the day try to do what's fair and practical.